What is the culprit? Singleton failure with WebApplicationFactory
When I debug the following code I found SqliteConnection that I registered with singleton lifetime is not singleton when resolved from within AddDbContext after execution reaches GetAsync("").
I addedd the following to verify that the singleton  fails.
if (!ReferenceEquals(_sharedConnection, connection))
    throw new ApplicationException("SqliteConnection should be singleton.");

What is the culprit and the workaround? The complete code is given as follows.
Web API under test
public class AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> o) : DbContext(o);

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        var app = builder.Build();

        app.MapGet("/", (AppDbContext db) => "Hello");

        app.Run();
    }
}

Test
public class CustomWebAppFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Program>
{
    private static SqliteConnection _sharedConnection = null!;

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        base.ConfigureWebHost(builder);

        builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
            services.RemoveAll(typeof(SqliteConnection));
            services.RemoveAll(typeof(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext>));

            services.AddSingleton(provider =>
            {
                var connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");
                return connection;
            });

            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>((provider, options) =>
            {
                var connection = provider.GetRequiredService<SqliteConnection>();

                if (!ReferenceEquals(_sharedConnection, connection))
                    throw new ApplicationException("SqliteConnection should be singleton.");

                options.UseSqlite(connection);
            });

            var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

            if (_sharedConnection != null)
                throw new ApplicationException("_sharedConnection should be null before reaching the following line.");

            _sharedConnection = provider.GetRequiredService<SqliteConnection>();
        });
    }
}

public class TrivialTest
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task Should_return_OK()
    {
        using var factory = new CustomWebAppFactory();
        using var client = factory.CreateClient();
        var response = await client.GetAsync("");
        Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
    }
}


Dependency injection scopes apply within a single IoC container. The ASP.NET Core web server is creating its container internally, but you created a separate container by manually calling into .BuildServiceProvider() yourself, and both of them have their own singleton connection. Don't do that.
If your connection is supposed to outlive the test, don't let the test server's container control the lifetime of the dependency and create it yourself (which is why the other answer happens to fix the problem, but explains why the problem happens badly)
Also you can get the service provider after the server is built, so there's no need for hacks like these.

Conclusion based on this answer:
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

var services = new ServiceCollection();

// version 1
services.AddSingleton(new Foo());

// version 2
services.AddSingleton(isp => new Foo());

for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
    var providers = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    var foo = providers.GetRequiredService<Foo>();
    // prints the same GUID for version 1 but different GUIDs for version 2
    foo.PrintId(); 
}

public class Foo
{
    private readonly Guid _id = Guid.NewGuid();
    public void PrintId() => Console.WriteLine(_id);
}

